# Fermat lemma proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Could anyone tell me if my proof is correct? Lemma states that when function $f(x)$ has a derivative at $p$ and additionally an extremum in this point, then $f'(p)=0$.

*Proof*

Let assume without loss of generality that $f$ has a local maximum in point $p$. It means that for all $x\in(x-\delta , x+\delta)$ for some $\delta$ we have $f(p)\geq f(x)$. This leads to the following observation 
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(p+h)-f(p)}{h}\leq 0 \Rightarrow f'(p)\leq 0$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(p+h)-f(p)}{h}\geq 0 \Rightarrow f'(p)\geq 0$$
Both inequalities are true iff $f'(p)=0$ which ends the proof.

Comment: It does look good, although I would write $$f'(p)=\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(p+h)-f(p)}{h}\le 0.$$